# Derive |- [(P>Q)>P]>P using only primitive rules

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic, peirce

I've been having issues trying to derive |- [(P>Q)>P]>P in natural deduction using only primitive rules. Wondering if anyone would have a solution to it.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if the rules I used are among those you are permitted to use. Could you list the rules in a comment or better edit your question and include the specific rules you are permitted to use? Welcome to this SE!

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to show this using modus tollens (MT), contradiction introduction (⊥I), explosion (X), conditional introduction (→I) and indirect proof (IP).

[image]

For context, what you are trying to show is [Peirce's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce%27s_law).

---

References

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/

Wikipedia, "Peirce's Law" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce%27s_law

Comment: **Note:** If Modus Tolens is not considered a *primative rule*, line 3 is not needed.  From lines 1 and 7 you may derive P by Modus Ponens (conditional elimination), which gives the needed contradition with the assumed ~P.

Comment: @GrahamKemp One should be able to do this without modus tollens. And there may be simpler ways to do it than the one I presented.